# Im trying to make this live tour work on my website but i have the following error, how do i resolve?

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-403, matterport

[The ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fsSP.png)
I've been having this problem for the past couple days and i can't seem to fix it. I'm trying to view a live tour in my website, but i get this 403 Forbidden access denied error. How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The status code 403 means that you can't consume the resource you're trying to. You probably need to pass a token or some identification to this request.

To understand 403 status code better, see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403